# getting users attending event data from facebook using FQL

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-fql

im having trouble getting information i want with fql.
i want to get the name and uid of all the people rsvped "attending" to a specific event sorted by name.
i know how to get all uid of the users attending to an event using the following query:

```
SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = ... AND rsvp_status = 'attending'
```

unfortunately event_member table doesn't have the name of the uid
and i know how to get the name and uid from event attenders using graph api, but the ther iss no way to get it sorted by name as far as i know.

your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer, i forgot there was a table called "user". the solution is

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN
 (
  SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = "EXISTING_EVENT_ID" and rsvp_status= "attending"
 ) 
SORT BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out FQL Query like

```
SELECT name, venue, location, start_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (
     SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = "USER_ID_HERE" and rsvp_status="attending"
 );
```

Comment: i need the names and uid of all the people coming to a certein event sorted by name, this seems to give me the information about all the events a spercific user attends